IntelliJ toString() debug object view not working on value class
I have a value class for Fractions:
@JvmInline
value class Fraction(private val value: Long) : Comparable<Fraction> {
    companion object {
        // Constant values for common fractions
        val ZERO = Fraction(0L shl 32 or 1)     // 0/1
        val ONE = Fraction(1L shl 32 or 1)      // 1/1
        val HALF = Fraction(1L shl 32 or 2)     // 1/2
        val THIRD = Fraction(1L shl 32 or 3)    // 1/3
        val QUARTER = Fraction(1L shl 32 or 4)  // 1/4
        val INFINITY = Fraction(Int.MAX_VALUE.toLong() shl 32 or 1) // ∞/1

        // Helper function to create a Fraction from numerator and denominator
        fun from(numerator: Int, denominator: Int): Fraction {
            require(denominator != 0) { "Denominator cannot be zero." }
            return Fraction((numerator.toLong() shl 32) or denominator.toLong())
        }
    }

    val numerator: Int
        get() = (value shr 32).toInt() // Get the numerator (higher bits)

    val denominator: Int
        get() = value.toInt()          // Get the denominator (lower bits)
    ...
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$numerator/$denominator"
    }

In the debugger, this shows as the underlying long which makes it unreadable. Enabling the toString() object view for this class would normally fix this but it does not show for value classes.
